# Указатель на динамический массив указателей C++

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, указатели, динамические-массивы

Я пишу лабораторную по работе с классами и указателями в C++. По условию, полем класса должен быть указатель на динамический массив указателей. Каждый указатель из этого массива установлен на начало динамического массива, который является строкой двумерной матрицы. Помогите, пожалуйста с реализацией этих требований.
Моё представление, о там, как должен выглядеть код, такое:

```
class Matrix {
private:
    int n;
    int m;
    int ***p;
public:
    ...
    A(int n, int m) {
        int **matrix = new int* [n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            matrix[i] = new int [m];
        p = &matrix;
    }
    ...
};
```

Правильно ли я предполагаю?

Comment: Обязательная шутка про [three star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int ***p;
// ...
A(int n, int m) {
    int **matrix = /*...*/;
    // ...
    p = &matrix;
}
```

Здесь вы сохраняете в `p` адрес локальной переменной `matrix`, которая разрушается сразу после выхода из конструктора. После этого любое чтение/запись по адресу, хранящемуся в `p`, будет вызывать неопределенное поведение.

Решение - поставить перед `p` на одну звездочку меньше:

```
int **p;
```

И работать в конструкторе напрямую с `p`:

```
A(int n, int m) : n(n), m(m) {
    p = new int* [n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        p[i] = new int [m];
}
```

Кроме того, вы не сохраняете переданные в конструктор размеры в поля класса. В коде выше это исправлено добавлением списка инициализации: `: n(n), m(m)`.

---

Еще:

Понятно, что ваш преподаватель скорее всего настаивает на прямом использовании `new`/`delete`.

Но в реальной жизни лушче использовать вместо этого `std::vector` (или другой подходящий контейнер или умный указатель), он намного удобнее и безопаснее:

```
class Matrix
{
  private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>>> p;

  public:
    A(int n, int m) : p(n, std::vector(m)) {}
};
```